# Selling xbox but want to keep digitally downloaded games

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

So I'm selling my xbox one, and plan on purchase another down the road.  I have downloaded games that I bought via xbox live.  I want to know if I can put the downloaded games on a thumb drive or just save them to my Microsoft account so that I dont have to purchase them again.  Please help!

Answer (score 45):

Your games are tied to your xbox live account. When you buy your new Xbox One, you just log in with your account and your games will be available to download again.
Before selling your Xbox though, you should reset it to factory defaults to remove any private information. You can do it by following these steps:

1. Open the Settings application
2. Scroll down to the System tab
3. Select Console info & updates
4. Navigate to the Reset console button.
5. Select the Reset and remove everything option. This will entirely
   wipe your console to a factory-fresh state.

[source](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-to-sell-your-xbox-one)

Comment: I've never owned an Xbox of any type, but I do wonder -- if the OP is selling the hard drive included, would they need to [scrub the hard drive too](https://www.pcworld.com/article/261702/how_to_securely_erase_your_hard_drive.html)?